# 16 bit HID axis operation

Tags: c++, arduino, hid, adc, 16-bit

I am having trouble get my Arduino HID Axis controller to read correctly in windows. I am using an older version of this code (https://github.com/MHeironimus/ArduinoJoystickLibrary) which I'm modifying to get rid of everything except the axis'.

```
#include "Joystick.h"

#if defined(_USING_HID)

#define JOYSTICK_REPORT_ID 0x03
#define JOYSTICK_STATE_SIZE 8

static const uint8_t _hidReportDescriptor[] PROGMEM = {

    // Joystick
    0x05, 0x01,               // USAGE_PAGE (Generic Desktop)
    0x09, 0x04,               // USAGE (Joystick)
    0xa1, 0x01,               // COLLECTION (Application)
    0x85, JOYSTICK_REPORT_ID, //   REPORT_ID (3)

    // 16 bit Throttle and Steering
    0x05, 0x02,               //   USAGE_PAGE (Simulation Controls)
    0x15, 0x00,               //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x27, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,         //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (65535)
    0xA1, 0x00,               //   COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x09, 0xBB,               //     USAGE (Throttle)
    0x09, 0xBA,               //     USAGE (Rudder)
    0x75, 0x10,               //     REPORT_SIZE (16)
    0x95, 0x02,               //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x02,               //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0xc0,                     //   END_COLLECTION



    // rx, ry, Axis
    0x05, 0x01,                 // Usage Page (Generic Desktop)
    //0x09, 0x01,           // Usage (Pointer)
    0x15, 0x00,                 //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
    0x27, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,         //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (65535)
    0xA1, 0x00,               //   COLLECTION (Physical)
    0x09, 0x33,               //     USAGE (rx)
    0x09, 0x34,               //     USAGE (ry)
    0x75, 0x10,                 //        REPORT_SIZE (16)
    0x95, 0x02,               //     REPORT_COUNT (2)
    0x81, 0x02,               //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
    0xc0,                     //   END_COLLECTION

    0xc0                      // END_COLLECTION
};

Joystick_::Joystick_()
{
    // Setup HID report structure
    static HIDSubDescriptor node(_hidReportDescriptor, sizeof(_hidReportDescriptor));
    HID().AppendDescriptor(&node);

    // Initalize State
    xAxisRotation = 0;
    yAxisRotation = 0;
    throttle = 0;
    rudder = 0;

}

void Joystick_::begin(bool initAutoSendState)
{
    autoSendState = initAutoSendState;
    sendState();
}

void Joystick_::end()
{
}


void Joystick_::setThrottle(uint16_t value)
{
    throttle = value;
    if (autoSendState) sendState();
}
void Joystick_::setRudder(uint16_t value)
{
    rudder = value;
    if (autoSendState) sendState();
}

void Joystick_::setXAxisRotation(uint16_t value)
{
    xAxisRotation = value;
    if (autoSendState) sendState();
}
void Joystick_::setYAxisRotation(uint16_t value)
{
    yAxisRotation = value;
    if (autoSendState) sendState();
}



void Joystick_::sendState()
{
    uint8_t data[JOYSTICK_STATE_SIZE];


  data[0] = throttle; //lsb
  data[1] = throttle >> 8; //msb
  data[2] = rudder;
  data[3] = rudder >> 8;
    data[4] = xAxisRotation;
    data[5] = xAxisRotation >> 8;
    data[6] = yAxisRotation;
    data[7] = yAxisRotation >> 8;

    // HID().SendReport(Report number, array of values in same order as HID descriptor, length)
    HID().SendReport(JOYSTICK_REPORT_ID, data, JOYSTICK_STATE_SIZE);
}

Joystick_ Joystick;

#endif
```

This is my cpp file

My 16 bit throttle and rudder work perfectly but my rx and ry rotation do not. I also can't get rid of my hat switches, all the AXIS stop working if i remove the hat switches and set the report size to 7.

I feel I'm not performing the bit shift or masking correctly, or I'm missing some commands to get it to put it together correctly.
Every time I try to remove buttons or axis from the .h file it completely break the controller and windows won't detect it. But I'm fine with leaving it alone if I can get the cpp file to just the 4 AXIS at 16bit.

I am using a BEETLE LEONARDO USB ATMEGA32U4 DEVELOPMENT BOARD with a ADS1115 over I2C. That was fun get get set up, this is my first Arduino project so I'm super new to this.

EDIT: I figured out how to get rid of the hat switches (updated my code). When I look at the raw data for the x and y rotations, in the calibration settings in windows, the numbers go from 0 to 65000 like my throttle and rudder do but the blue bar graph starts at 1900-2000 and is not a %value like the throttle and rudder are. Do I have to change the maximum values for these axis'?

Comment: I can't explain the 1900-2000 range (other than it is some Windows quirk), but you could try to assign physical units to the Rx and Ry values to coax Windows into displaying them as degrees of rotation. For example,

    `0x65, 0x14,               //     Unit (degrees)`

    `0x35, 0x00,               //     Physical Minimum (0)`

    `0x46, 0x68, 0x01,         //     Physical Maximum (360)`

Comment: How do I set it to a linear value instead of degrees?
`
0x35, 0x00,               //     Physical Minimum (0)
0x47, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00,         //     Physical Maximum (360)
`
Is what I tried with the same result.
I think maybe your onto something with the degrees. It might be stuck on a rotation value?

Comment: `
 0x15, 0x00,         //   LOGICAL_MINIMUM (0)
 0x26, 0xff, 0x00,       //   LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (255)
 0x75, 0x08,         //   REPORT_SIZE (8)
 0x09, 0x01,         //   USAGE (Pointer)
 0xA1, 0x00,         //   COLLECTION (Physical)
 0x09, 0x30,            //     USAGE (x)
 0x09, 0x31,            //     USAGE (y)
 0x09, 0x32,            //     USAGE (z)
 0x09, 0x33,            //     USAGE (rx)
 0x09, 0x34,            //     USAGE (ry)
 0x09, 0x35,            //     USAGE (rz)
 0x95, 0x06,            //     REPORT_COUNT (6)
 0x81, 0x02,            //     INPUT (Data,Var,Abs)
`

Comment: `void Joystick_::setXAxisRotation(int16_t value)
{
 xAxisRotation = value;
 if (autoSendState) sendState();
}`

`data[10] = (xAxisRotation % 360) * 0.708;`
 `data[11] = (yAxisRotation % 360) * 0.708;`
 `data[12] = (zAxisRotation % 360) * 0.708;`

This is all the original code for the x rotation.

Sorry for the blocks of text, I'm new to this stuff hahaha!